# Scylladb/Apache cassandra data modelling

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, scylla

I want to model the following logic with Apache Cassandra/ScyllaDb, but I fail to figure out how to properly model the tables.

The query that I want to apply has the following general idea :

For a specific user, I want to retrieve items ordered by a timestamp field where the item is active (active field = true). The retrieved items should be distinct and they are limited to max 10 / select query.

Basically, I want to satisfy the following sql logic :

```
Select * from TABLE where user_id = 'EXAMPLE_ID' and timestamp < EXAMPLE_TIMESTAMP and active = true ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 10;
```

In this model, the timestamp is a write-heavy field which gets updated very frequently. The active field can also be updated, however this operation is not that frequent.

This is the model that I came up with until now :

```
    CREATE TABLE items
    (
        user_id   text,
        item_id   uuid,
        timestamp bigint
        ...other columns
        PRIMARY KEY (user_id, item_id)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (item_id DESC);
```

This table represents the items for a user.

Further, I created the following materialized view :

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW items_by_timestamp AS
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL
  AND timestamp IS NOT NULL
  AND item_id IS NOT NULL 
PRIMARY KEY (user_id, timestamp, item_id)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);
```

The materialized view would then allow me to query for X items based on the given timestamp in the correct order(s the materialized view is sorted by timestamp) using the following query :

```
Select * from items_by_timestamp where user_id = 'EXAMPLE_ID' and timestamp < EXAMPLE_TIMESTAMP.
```

Until now I am able to satisfy the timestamp ordering. However I fail to see how I can further add the active query.
Since the timestamp is not part of the "items" table primary key, I can not add the "active" column as part of the primary key to the materialized view (only 1 non-primary key column from the base table is allowed).

If I add the active flag to the base table, I can no longer update the active flag since that would create a new row in the table.
If I add the timestamp as a base table primary key, I would then be able to add the active flag in the materialized view, but then I would no longer be able to update the timestamp, again since timestamp is part of the pk.

The only other alternative that I see that would allow me to do this is to use local secondary indexes, however I read that they do not scale well at all. Would this be the correct approach, keeping in mind that the timestamp field update is a very frequent operation and the active field update is not so frequent ?